# if cell A value contains some words then print yes in column B

Tags: excel, vba

test in excels it is working fine as shown in screenshot. when i use them in macro i am getting syntax error

code i used in  macros.

```
Sub test()
r = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("$M2:$M100"&r&" ").Formula ="IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("latitude 5400",K2)), "No", "Yes")"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing: `Range("$M2:$M100"&r&" ").` for `Range("$M2:$M" & r).`

Comment: still it shows end of statement is needed r = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("$M2:$M100" & r & " ").Formula = "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("latitude 5400",K2)), "No", "Yes")"

Comment: Try recording a working formula with the Macro Recording button and take your formula from there just chaning the range with your variables. That's what I do when I'm stuck with formula stuff.

Comment: If you need a quote character within a string in VBA, you have to double it so that the VBA compiler knows that this is not the end of a string. `"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""latitude 5400"",K2)), ""No"", ""Yes"")"`

Comment: thank you@FunThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()
r = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("$M2:$M" & r).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""latitude 5400"",K2)), ""No"", ""Yes"")"
End Sub
```